# Trouble with the output

Tags: java

The following code creates an error for me after running it, it projects the first line "Please enter length of a rectangle." correctly, but then the next line after I input a number is "Enter the length of the rectangle: Please enter width of a rectangle." Then after I input the second time it creates an error and crashes my code. To clarify I don't mean to have those next to each other like that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaRectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double length,     // The rectangle's length
                width,     // The rectangle's width
                area;      // The rectangle's area

        // Get the rectangle's length from the user.
        length = getLength();
        System.out.print("Enter the length of " +
                "the rectangle: ");

        // Get the rectangle's width from the user.
        width = getWidth();
        System.out.print("Enter the width of " +
                "the rectangle: ");

        // Get the rectangle's area.
        area = getArea(length, width);
        System.out.print("The area of the " +
                "rectangle is: ");

        // Display the rectangle data.
        displayData(length, width, area);
        System.out.print("Enter the length of " +
                "the rectangle: ");
    }

    public static double getLength() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter length of a rectangle.");
        double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The length of the rectangle is " + length);
        return length;
    }

    public static double getWidth() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double width;
        System.out.println("Please enter width of a rectangle.");
        width = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The width of the rectangle is " + width);
        return width;
    }

    public static double getArea(double length, double width) {
        double area = length * width;
        System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is " + area);
        return area;
    }

    public static double displayData(double length, double width, double
            area) {
        System.out.println("The length of the rectangle is: \t" + length);
        System.out.println("The width of the rectangle is: \t" + width);
        System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: \t" + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Javascript` is not `Java`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Enter the length of the rectangle: Please enter width of a rectangle. I would like to know how to get rid of the first part

Comment: Any particular reason why you put the prompt to enter the width/length/area after the methods that accept the values for those variables?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return value from the getLength function.

Just add a return statement on it and it will work.

you have declared:

```
public static double displayData(....)
```

so you MUST return a double value or change your function declaration to

```
public static void displayData
```

You have also another problem with your main function: you can delete all the println on the main scope. You can also remove the println inside getArea function. your code will be like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class AreaRectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double length,     // The rectangle's length
                width,     // The rectangle's width
                area;      // The rectangle's area

```
    // Get the rectangle's length from the user.
    length = getLength();


    // Get the rectangle's width from the user.
    width = getWidth();

    // Get the rectangle's area.
    area = getArea(length, width);

    // Display the rectangle data.
    displayData(length, width, area);

}

public static double getLength() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter length of a rectangle.");
    double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The length of the rectangle is " + length);
    return length;
}

public static double getWidth() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double width;
    System.out.println("Please enter width of a rectangle.");
    width = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The width of the rectangle is " + width);
    return width;
}

public static double getArea(double length, double width) {
    double area = length * width;
    return area;
}

public static void displayData(double length, double width, double
        area) {
    System.out.println("The length of the rectangle is: \t" + length);
    System.out.println("The width of the rectangle is: \t" + width);
    System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: \t" + area);
}
```

}

and the output of your console will be ok for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the prompts from `main()`. 
   The proper prompts are inside the other methods.
2. In each method that you open a Scanner object, 
   don't forget to close it just before the `return` statement: `keyboard.close();`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you. Take a look how it is implemented and try adding some new features like parameter or diagonal of the rectangle. It isn't that hard.

```
public class Main {
    private static double lengthOfRectangle;
    private static double widthOfRectangle;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the length of the rectangle: \n");
        lengthOfRectangle = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Input the length of the rectangle: \n");
        widthOfRectangle = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Length: %s - Width: %s - Area of your rectangle is %s", lengthOfRectangle,widthOfRectangle,lengthOfRectangle*widthOfRectangle);

    }




}
```